# What themes are those under Controls in Cinnamon themes?

Tags: linux, cinnamon, gtk, theme, metacity

I have installed many Cinnamon themes but those listed under Desktop affect mostly the Panel, not the windows texture:

[image]

The window frame is set under Windows Borders, but what I am interested in is the theme under Controls.

[image]

I know that themes are categorized as GTK, Metacity etc. Which is which in Cinnamon?

Windows=?
Controls=?
Desktop=?